# The limit of consecutive positive integers which are the product of n primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, products

The maximum length of a string of consecutive primes is 2: that is, the primes 2, 3. This is easily proven, as no even number other than 2 is prime.

In contrast, consider the set of numbers which are a product of exactly two primes (they don't need to be distinct). This set begins 4, 6, 9, 10, 12 ...
It goes on to include the numbers 33, 34, 35 - a run of three consecutive integers. Is this the longest consecutive run of such numbers?

My conjecture: that each set of numbers which are the product of exactly n primes contains one and only one run of consecutive numbers which is n+1 long.

No idea whether this is true! Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: Out of four consecutive numbers, one is divisible by $4$. It follows that we cannot have four consecutive numbers that are products of $2$ primes.

Comment: They don't need to be distinct right?  Like 25 counts as a semiprime

Comment: Have you tried to find a run of four consecutive numbers that are the product of three primes? Are you requiring the primes to be distinct?

Comment: Good clarification.  The primes don't need to be distinct.

Comment: you should consider $\omega(n) = \sum_{p | n} 1$ instead, the number of distinct primes factors of $n$, without caring of the multiplicity

Comment: That's a good point. How would the situation be different if we were just considering the number of distinct prime factors? I'm guessing you then could have a run of 4 numbers which have exactly 2 distinct primes (at least, the restriction described above wouldn't apply).

Comment: The OEIS entry https://oeis.org/A045984 is "The smallest number $m$ such that factorizations of $n$ consecutive integers starting at $m$ have [the] same number of primes (counted with multiplicity)".   For example $a(3) = 33$ in this sequence.  Searching for 211763 in OEIS gives a lot of sequences related to prime factorizations of consecutive integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits each time are defined by the powers of $2$. So a consecutive set of numbers which each have exactly two prime factors (not necessarily distinct) will be bounded by the need to avoid multiples of $2^4=4$ (given that including $4$ itself is not an option).

And a consecutive set of numbers which have exactly three prime factors (not necessarily distinct) will be bounded by the need to avoid multiples of $2^3=8$. So we can possibly expect a run of $7$ such numbers, and the smallest such run starts at $211763$:
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
n &f_1 & f_2 & f_3 \\ \hline
211673 & 7 & 11 & 2749 \\
211674 & 2 & 3 & 35279 \\
211675 & 5 & 5 & 8467 \\
211676 & 2 & 2 & 52919 \\
211677 & 3 & 37 & 1907 \\
211678 & 2 & 109 & 971 \\
211679 & 13 & 19 & 857 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: A decent long run of numbers with four prime factors would require inclusion of a number $8$ times a prime. The best run under $10$ million is a set of nine consecutive numbers starting at $3405122$.

Comment: Great job finding such a run - how did you do it? Are there more such runs of 7? Will a run of 15 also exists for 4-prime numbers?

Comment: @ThomasDelaney pretty much a straight search for the 7-run of 3-factor numbers. There are 61 such sequences under 10 million. I 'm guessing there will be a 15-run of 4-factor numbers, but also that it will require a very large number space to allow such a coincidence to occur. The 9-run at 3405122 is the only one below 10 million.